# Why does reading from /dev/random nearly always block?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm using kubuntu with kernel 2.6.38-12-generic

I want to read 16 random numbers from /dev/random at the start of my program.
However, it blocks after a relatively short time.

How long does it take for the /dev/random buffer to fill?  why is it taking so long to fill.

I'm using this as a uuid generator with other sources of randomness added to seed 
my mersenne twister.  It's critical that I don't get duplicates or a duplicate seed.

If I change to /dev/urandom it works ok.  Any view on using /dev/random over /dev/urandom.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/359599/why-is-my-dev-random-so-slow-when-using-dd

Comment: For modern Linux kernels, this is no longer the case, see [this article on lwn.net](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/) for the relevant background information, plus [this relevant thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693160/how-can-i-force-dev-random-to-block) on Unix StackExchange pointing out that Linux kernel 5.6 and later, `/dev/random` only blocks when the CRNG has not been initialized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You really should never use `/dev/random`. There are no known circumstances where the advantages of `/dev/random` over `/dev/urandom` matter, and the disadvantages are pretty obvious.

The difference is that `/dev/urandom` provides 'merely' cryptographically-secure random numbers while `/dev/random` provides truly random numbers (at least, that is what we believe). But there is no known situation where this difference matters and no known test that can distinguish "true" randomness from merely cryptographically-secure randomness.

I usually joke that `/dev/urandom` provides water and `/dev/random` provides holy water.

Comment: It is more correct to say that no known polynomial time algorithm can distinguish between /dev/urandom and a true random stream more than a negligibly small percentage of the time.

Answer (score 6):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/random) of `man 4 random` answers the question:

> When read, the `/dev/random` device will only return random bytes 
>   within the estimated number of bits of noise in the entropy pool. 
>   `/dev/random` should be suitable for uses that need very high quality
>   randomness such as  one-time  pad  or  key generation.  When the
>   entropy pool is empty, reads from `/dev/random` will block until
>   additional environmental noise is gathered.

I'm so surprised people prefer asking than reading the man pages! You don't even need Internet to read the man pages of your system.

BTW, as I commented, the entropy pool is fed by physical phenomena (depends of the hardware), like e.g. mouse movements, key presses, ethernet packets, etc. Some few processors have a hardware random noise generator (e.g. the [`RDRAND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) machine instruction), and you can buy [random USB devices](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/usb-hardware-random-number-generator/) (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators) list), etc.... Hence reading from `/dev/random` could be expansive (or even blocking). You'll use it for high quality randomness (e.g. required by cryptographic keys) or, at initialization, for seeding your [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). You should expect `/dev/random` to have a relatively small bandwidth (e.g. a few kilobytes or at most a megabyte per second at most) and it could have a lot of latency (dozens of milliseconds, or even more). Details are of course computer specific.

Read also Thomas Hühn's [*Myths about `/dev/urandom`*](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)

Comment: Actually I have read this.  I should have asked "why does the entropy pool empty so quickly when I'm only reading maybe 100 4 byte ints numbers max?  and then it takes a long time to be able to read much more from it.

Comment: The "entropy pool" is fed by physical phenomena (depends of the hardware), like e.g. mouse movements, key presses, ethernet packets, etc. Some few processors have a hardware random noise generator (but not all), but most haven't. So `/dev/random` is expensive!

Answer (score 4):

Reading from /dev/random is non-determinstic, because all it does is fetch the requested number of bits from the random pool. It will block until it can read the requested number of bits.

/dev/urandom, however, is the kernel's PRNG, and can supply a near-infinite stream of pseudo-random numbers.